# c sudoku solver with recursive backtracking returning errors

Tags: c, recursion, sudoku, backtracking, solver

Hey everyone so I wrote a sudoku solver in C that uses recursive backtracking. However the output is not what's expected.For the code to work you need to pass in an array of 81 numbers, and the 0 on the board equals a '.' in the array. The problem is that my output starts filling in everything with 1's in place of where the '.'. I dont understand why and  I need a fresh pair of eyes to look it over for me.

```
#define DEBUG FALSE
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

#include <stdio.h>

/* function declarations */
int readPuzzle(int puzzle[9][9]);
int findRowErrors(int puzzle[9][9]);
int findColErrors(int puzzle[9][9]);
int findBoxErrors(int puzzle[9][9]);
int solvePuzzle(int puzzle[9][9], int index);
int validMove(int puzzle[9][9], int index, int num);
int noSolution(int puzzle[9][9]);
void writePuzzle(int puzzle[9][9]);

int main (void)
{
  int puzzle[9][9];
  int index = 0;
  int error;

  while ((error = readPuzzle(puzzle)) != EOF)
    {
      error += findRowErrors(puzzle);
      error += findColErrors(puzzle);
      error += findBoxErrors(puzzle);

  if (error) printf("Error\n\n");
  else
    {
      /* in DEBUG mode, show initial puzzle in standard sudoku form */
      if (DEBUG) writePuzzle(puzzle);
      solvePuzzle(puzzle, index);
      if (!noSolution(puzzle)) writePuzzle(puzzle);
    }
}
  return 0;
}

int readPuzzle(int puzzle[9][9])
{
  int i, num, row, col;
  int error = FALSE;

  for (i = 0; (num = getchar()) != '\n'; i++)
    {
      if (num == EOF) return EOF;
      putchar(num);
      if ((num < '1' || num > '9') && (num != '.')) error = TRUE;
      if (num == '.') num = '0';

      row = (i / 9) % 9;
      col = i % 9;
      puzzle[row][col] = num - '0';
    }
  putchar('\n');
  if (i != 81) error = TRUE;
  return error;
 }

  int findRowErrors(int puzzle[9][9])
{
  int row, col, i;

  /* check rows */
  for (row = 0; row < 9; row++)
    {
      for (col = 0; col < 9; col++)
        {
          for (i = col + 1; i < 9; i++)
            {
              if ( (puzzle[row][col] != 0) && (puzzle[row][col] ==    puzzle[row][i]) )
            {
              return TRUE;                      /* row error found in puzzle\
 */
                }
            }
        }
     }   

  return FALSE;
}



int findColErrors(int puzzle[9][9])
{
  int row, col, i;
  for (col = 0; col < 9; col++)
    {
      for (row = 0; row < 9; row++)
        {
          for (i = row + 1; i < 9; i++)
             {
              if ( (puzzle[row][col] != 0) && (puzzle[row][col] == puzzle[i][col]) )
                {
                  return TRUE;                      /* column error found in          puzzle */
                 }
            }
         }  
    }
   return FALSE;
 }




int findBoxErrors(int puzzle[9][9])
{
  int row, col, i, j;
  for (row = 0; row < 9; row += 3)
    {
      for (col = 0; col < 9; col += 3)
        {
          for (i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            {
              for (j = i + 1; j < 9; j++)
                {
                  if ( (puzzle[row + i / 3][col + i % 3] != 0) &&
                       (puzzle[row + i / 3][col + i % 3] ==
                        puzzle[row + j / 3][col + j % 3]) )
                    {
                      return TRUE;                  /* box error found in     puzzle*/
                    }
                }
            }
     }
    }
  return FALSE;
}


 int noSolution(int puzzle[9][9])
 {
  int row, col;
  for (row = 0; row < 9; row++)
    {
       for (col = 0; col < 9; col++)
        {
          if (!puzzle[row][col])
            {
              printf("No solution\n\n");
              return TRUE;
            }
        }
    }
  return FALSE;
}


void writePuzzle(int puzzle[9][9])
{
  int row, col;
  for (row = 0; row < 9; row++)
    {
      if (DEBUG) printf("\n");
      if ((DEBUG) && (row == 3 || row == 6))
        {
          printf("----------------------\n");
        }
      for (col = 0; col < 9; col++)
        {
          if (DEBUG) printf(" ");
          if (puzzle[row][col]) printf("%d", puzzle[row][col]);
          else printf(".");
          if ((DEBUG) && (col == 2 || col == 5)) printf(" |");
        }
    }
  printf("\n\n");
}



int solvePuzzle(int puzzle[9][9], int index)
{
  int num;
  int row = index / 9;
  int col = index % 9;

  if (index == 81) return TRUE;                 /* all cells are filled */

  if (puzzle[row][col] != 0)
    {
      return solvePuzzle(puzzle, ++index);        /* recursive call */
    }

  else
    {
       for (num = 1; num <= 9; num++)
        {
          if (validMove(puzzle, index, num))
            {
              puzzle[row][col] = num;
              if (solvePuzzle(puzzle, index)) return TRUE;
              puzzle[row][col] = 0;
            }
        }
      return FALSE;
    }
}


  /*Checks to see Valid moves for rows, columns, and regions*/
  int validMove(int puzzle[9][9],int start, int num)

  {
    int r, c;
    int row = start / 9;
    int column = start % 9;
    int regionFirstRow = row - (row %3 );
    int regionFirstColumn = column - (row % 3);


  /*Checks rows for valid moves*/
    for(c = 0; c < 9; c++)
      {
         if(puzzle[row][c] == num)
          {
            return FALSE;
           }
      }
    /*Checks columns for valid moves*/
    for(r = 0; r < 9; r++)
      {
        if(puzzle[r][column] == num)
          {
            return FALSE;
          }
      }

    /*FINISH THIS!!!!!!!!!*/
    /*Checks each 3x3 region for valid moves*/
    for(r = 0; r < 3; r++)
      {
        for(c = 0; c < 3; c++)
          {
            if(puzzle[regionFirstRow + r][regionFirstColumn + c] == num)
              {
                return FALSE;
  }
          }
      }
    return TRUE;
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.  Specifically, your posted code hangs (perhaps waiting for input you didn't give it), and you fail to show actual and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in the box region calculation in function `validMove`

```
int regionFirstColumn = column - (row % 3);
```

should be

```
int regionFirstColumn = column - (column % 3);
```

Comment: It's definitely something in validMove that is causing the error, just trying to figure out which section. input is appreciated

Comment: nvm I ran it again after it was compiled and it worked!!!!! you rock